# How to create primary partition after having an extended one?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and formatted the hard drive by creating swap, root and home partitions. Their total volume is 32 GB all together. So I logged on to the system, installed GParted and run it to partition the rest of the hard disks space. But what I see is that swap is on /dev/sda1 and the two other partitions (root and home) are located on /dev/sda2 . 
I am so afraid to create a new partition since GParted only offers the choice of creating a primary one only. Should I dare to create a new partition (with the conditions told) and format it? Where can I see a complete reference on partitioning disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like /deb/sda2 is an extended partition.

It can contain multiple logical partitions.

In your case you can increase size of /dev/sda2 and create some more logical partitions in it, or create a new primary partition.

You need to consider that you can have only one extended partition and no more than 4 primary partitions (including extended).

Comment: Then , could I create a primary one without having the fear of losing my data?

Comment: When you create partitions there is no risk to lose data. But you need to know that this will be the last primary partition you can create.

Comment: I found little more details here on : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition